# Импорт Книг Excel в SPSS

Tags: excel, r, импорт

Необходимо создать одну базу данных для дальнейшего анализа, однако данные хранятся в 12 (случаев) книгах по 10 (человек) листов в каждой с одинаковыми отведениями ээг. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

`readxl::read_excel()` в R, затем сохранить в одну таблицу и уже ее открывать в SPSS (не буду даже спрашивать, зачем).

Answer (score 0):

Фрагмент работающего кода по объединение данных из таблиц MS Excel

```
# подключаем требуемые библиотеки
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)

# папка с файлам
fldr.xls <- "/home/om/Desktop/Fls"

# получили список файлов
fls.xls <- list.files(path  = fldr.xls, full.names = TRUE)

# определили количество файлов
n.fls <- length(fls.xls)

# 
for (n in 1:n.fls){
  # работаем с файлом
  nm.fl <- fls.xls[n]

  # опеределяем количество листов в таблице
  nm.sheets <- excel_sheets(nm.fl)
  n.sheets <- length(nm.sheets)

  print("=========================")
  print(paste0("Обработан файл:", nm.fl))
  print("Листы: ")

  # перебираем листы в таблице
  for (i in 1:n.sheets){
    # открываем таблицу с требуемым листом
    df.xls <- read_excel(fls.xls[n], sheet = nm.sheets[i])
    # 
    print(nm.sheets[i])

    # пишем в таблицу
    if (n == 1) {
      df.all <- df.xls 
      df.all <- df.all %>% mutate("File" = nm.fl, "Sheet" = nm.sheets[i])
    }
    else {
      df.xls <- df.xls %>% mutate("File" = nm.fl, "Sheet" = nm.sheets[i])
      df.all <- rbind(df.all, df.xls)
    }
  }
}
```

Далее `df.all` сохраняем для дальнейшей работы.